# Reading a JSON value post writing it in a .js file using fs.writeFileAsync gives undefined

Tags: javascript, protractor, bluebird

I am writing values to a JSON file during my test execution in a function using -

```
 var Promise = require ('../../node_modules/bluebird');
 var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

 fs.writeFileAsync(fileName, text).then(function (){

     console.log( "Data written successfully");
 });
```

It writes the value in a .js file in the below format -

```
 var json =  {

    "TestVal" : "Test123",
    "Test"  : ['1','2','3']
 };
 module.exports = json;
```

Next during the course of the execution when trying to access these values it gives undefined in my protractor test . Am trying it fetch it like -

```
  var jsonData =  require('../../../Test_Data/Data_Sets/Json_Data.js');

  describe('TS : Test', function() {

     it('TC :Check the json value', function() {
        console.log ( jsonData.TestVal);
        console.log ( jsonData.Test);
     });
  });
```

In the console it gives undefined. Can it be a case that the write operation is not yet saved?

Comment: What is `fileName`, what is `text`, where do they come from?

Comment: Do you really expect this code to be executed only once, when the module is intialised (required for the first time)?

Comment: Yes, `writeFileAsync` is asynchronous. If you try to read it immediately after having begun writing, it won't be written yet.

Comment: fileName and text is the .js file name where the value in son format , i.e. text is to be written. My scenario is to invoke a webpage once and store certain values in the .js file and next invoke another page and do some validations with the stored values from the .js file. Is there a way to wait for writeFileAsync to complete and then do the read operation from the file?

Comment: i already tried fs.writeFileSync and got undefined !